# Run all running service tasks on EventBridge trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I have an ECS cluster service with ±10 running tasks constantly. Whenever an event pattern from an EventBridge rule triggers (p. ex CPUUtilization hits 50%), I want it to trigger a background job on all running tasks.

From what I have gathered so far, the only remotely close solution was to initially publish to an SNS Topic from EventBridge and then  subscribe to that topic via HTTP protocol or Lambda. For either case, if I have 10 running tasks will they all subscribe to the topic or only the first one that picks it up?

Answer (score 0):

> publish to an SNS Topic from EventBridge and then subscribe to that topic via HTTP protocol or Lambda. For either case, if I have 10 running tasks will they all subscribe to the topic or only the first one that picks it up?

You say for either case, but the cases are totally different. If you use Lambda, then the Lambda function gets the event, not your ECS tasks. It's unclear how you are expecting to be able to use Lambda to accomplish your goal here at all. I supposed you could have the Lambda function query for all the running tasks, then have it send an `ecs exec` command to each task. The Lambda function will just get a single message from EventBridge and it will have to be smart enough to fan-out the action to all the ECS tasks.

If you subscribe to the SNS topic via HTTP, then each ECS task would need to be running an HTTP server, and each one would have to subscribe to SNS as part of their startup process, and unsubscribe when they shut down. In that scenario, SNS would send a copy of the message to each of the task's HTTP endpoints.